# Windows 11 22H2 - How to fix unwanted padding added to the left side of the item in File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11-v22h2

I upgraded Windows 11 to 22H2 and now I have unwanted padding on the left side of each item in File Explorer.

The padding is only visible if the ListView is selected.
Compact mode settings do not have any impact on the issue.

Any ideas on how can this be resolved?

This area is not for the Folder Tree selection tick/check.

Please see below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWgp4.png

Answer (score 0):

The space you see at the left is for the Folder Tree selection arrows.  Also see the follow up note at the bottom as some of this padding is new in 22H2 newest version.

Based on your picture, nothing is wrong and what you see is how Windows 11 File Explorer works.

Compact view affects line spacing (and works) and has nothing to do with the folder tree.

The arrows ( > ) are dynamic on the screen and I was not able to capture them with either Snipping Tool or Snagit.

But look closely and the arrows in your padded space are there and nothing is wrong.  Move your mouse into the File Explorer space and you will see the arrows   (  >  ). If you move your mouse out of the space the arrows go away.

I looked at Windows 11 Insider (25215.100) and File Explorer works the same way in Insider (Left side arrows disappear when mouse leaves the Explorer Window.

If there is additional space (not on any of my Windows 11 Pro machines), try running DISM and SFC.

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. 
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth 
(4) SFC /SCANNOW 
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

I have my doubts as to whether DISM will fix your issue, but there is no such extra space on any of my Explorer Windows and otherwise I am not sure what might have happened to cause this. It is not an endemic Windows 11 issue to the best of my knowledge.

**Follow up note for 22H2:**

From pureintotech.com:  Padding is being added to some apps and menus.

So I think what you are seeing is normal for 22H2 newest updates.